# SSMS Filter Data by a datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date time field "createdDTTM" in format 2009-07-27 15:22:57.427

I want to extract data by applying the filter from date 1st Januray, 2019 to 31st Januray 2019.

I have tried everything I know. Cast, Convert, Date with various combinations but everything rendered ineffective.

i have tried following code:

```
SELECT p.fullname,
       p.dateofbirth,
       po.enterprisemrn,
       pro.FullName,
       o.OrderName,
       o.createdDTTM,
       o.WherePerformed,
       o.OrderNumberEXT,
       a.LocationName,
       a.apptnumberEXT,
       OrderStatus
FROM report.AHS_Order o
     JOIN report.AHS_Provider pro ON o.OrderingProviderID = pro.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient p ON p.ID = o.PatientID
     JOIN report.AHS_Appointment a ON a.PatientID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Iorg pio ON pio.personID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Other po ON po.id = p.ID
WHERE p.IsInactiveFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.IsDeceasedFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.LastName <> 'test'
  AND p.LastName <> 'allscripts'
  AND o.OrderStatus = 'Active'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Complete'
  AND pio.OrganizationName LIKE '%starling%'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'In Progress'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Need Information'
  AND o.OrderType = 'L'
  AND CONVERT(date, o.createdDTTM) > CONVERT(date, '20190101');
```

I also attempted with Cast(), Dateadd(dd,.....), I do not know anything else of.

**Can somebody please suggest what pattern of code is wrong in the where clause?**

See date column image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lekqI.png)

Comment: "this just doesnt seem to work" please post the code you are trying to use. It's easier to fix something half-done than doing it from scratch. Solution might simply be to write the date in iso format yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: please add your code to the question, not comments, then it's easier to see and can be formatted nicely. You can use the "edit" button (just under the blue sql-server tag) to modify your question. And also please show us a sample of the data you are working with in your table, and the result you want from your query, based on that data. Then it will be a lot clearer for us. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, again it would be much clearer if we have some sample data and expected results, too. Always make it as easy as possible for people to help you...that way you'll get more help :-)

Comment: Good use of whitespace and line breaks is really important when writing SQL. It makes the code you write not only readable for yourself but others as well. Ragged Left alligned SQL is never easy to read unless it's a very simplistic query (Like `Select Column FROM Table Where ID = 1;`)

Comment: I  have added the image of column. let me know if anything else would explain this situation better. @Larnu

Comment: The problem is likely to be your `OR`'s and lack of parenthesis. I could *guess* the logic you are after but if you use parenthesis you'll likely fix the issue.

Comment: I agree with Larnu. You should read about the precedence of AND and OR in this kind of situation. Very likely the logic is making the date condition optional. When working with ORs in particular you should always use appropriate brackets (parentheses) around the clauses to make your logical intention completely clear.

Comment: Thanks alot ADyson and Larnu. Thank you very much. IT did worked out like magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be caused by the `OR`s in your where clause. Try something like this:

```
SELECT p.fullname,
       p.dateofbirth,
       po.enterprisemrn,
       pro.FullName,
       o.OrderName,
       o.createdDTTM,
       o.WherePerformed,
       o.OrderNumberEXT,
       a.LocationName,
       a.apptnumberEXT,
       OrderStatus
FROM report.AHS_Order o
     JOIN report.AHS_Provider pro ON o.OrderingProviderID = pro.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient p ON p.ID = o.PatientID
     JOIN report.AHS_Appointment a ON a.PatientID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Iorg pio ON pio.personID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Other po ON po.id = p.ID
WHERE ( p.IsInactiveFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.IsDeceasedFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.LastName <> 'test'
  AND p.LastName <> 'allscripts'
  AND o.OrderStatus = 'Active'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Complete'
  AND pio.OrganizationName LIKE '%starling%'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'In Progress'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Need Information'
  AND o.OrderType = 'L' )
  AND o.createdDTTM > '20190101'
  AND o.createdDTTM < '20190201'
```

This uses parenthesis to apply the date to any other conditions matched in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Then this should work if o.createdDTTM is a datetime field

```
SELECT p.fullname,
       p.dateofbirth,
       po.enterprisemrn,
       pro.FullName,
       o.OrderName,
       o.createdDTTM,
       o.WherePerformed,
       o.OrderNumberEXT,
       a.LocationName,
       a.apptnumberEXT,
       OrderStatus
FROM report.AHS_Order o
     JOIN report.AHS_Provider pro ON o.OrderingProviderID = pro.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient p ON p.ID = o.PatientID
     JOIN report.AHS_Appointment a ON a.PatientID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Iorg pio ON pio.personID = p.ID
     JOIN report.AHS_Patient_Other po ON po.id = p.ID
WHERE p.IsInactiveFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.IsDeceasedFLAG = 'N'
  AND p.LastName <> 'test'
  AND p.LastName <> 'allscripts'
  AND o.OrderStatus = 'Active'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Complete'
  AND pio.OrganizationName LIKE '%starling%'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'In Progress'
   OR o.OrderStatus = 'Need Information'
  AND o.OrderType = 'L'

  AND (o.createdDTTM >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND o.createdDTTM <='2019-01-31 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Nope !  sorry mahn !! but just tried it bro. Still the records from 2018 pop up.

Comment: Kaustubh, once again please show us some sample data and expected results. Then we can try to reproduce your actual issue instead of having to guess. Help us to help you!

Comment: Why do I have a feeling that field `o.createDTTM` is a VARCHAR and not a DATETIME?

Comment: Maybe. How can I check that? @HardCode

Comment: @KaustubhUrsekar you should have SQL Server Management Studio installed? Connect to the DB and use the Explorer to view the table's columns.

Comment: createdDTTM(Datetime,null). this is what it shows in Obj. Exp. and columns folder of "order" table.